# facing problem to push data to backend from local storage in react

Tags: python, reactjs, django, redux, django-rest-framework

**I tried alot to fix that but I need little help to figure out what I'm doing wrong.**

When I make post request `POST /api/appointment/make/` Request gets failed with status code 500

```
Internal Server Error: /api/appointment/make/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\eCommerce_Projects\remote-hospital-v3\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "E:\eCommerce_Projects\remote-hospital-v3\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "E:\eCommerce_Projects\remote-hospital-v3\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\eCommerce_Projects\remote-hospital-v3\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 70, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\eCommerce_Projects\remote-hospital-v3\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 509, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "E:\eCommerce_Projects\remote-hospital-v3\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "E:\eCommerce_Projects\remote-hospital-v3\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "E:\eCommerce_Projects\remote-hospital-v3\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 506, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\eCommerce_Projects\remote-hospital-v3\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\decorators.py", line 50, in handler
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\eCommerce_Projects\remote-hospital-v3\panel\views\appointment_views.py", line 19, in makeAppointments
    membersToHeldMeeting = data['membersToHeldMeeting']
KeyError: 'membersToHeldMeeting'
[17/Jul/2021 23:52:27] "POST /api/appointment/make/ HTTP/1.1" 500 106441
```

First take a look at backend
urls
`path('api/appointment/make/', views.makeAppointments, name='appointment-add'),`

Related view

```
@api_view(['POST'])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
def makeAppointments(request):
    user = request.user
    data = request.data

    membersToHeldMeeting = data['membersToHeldMeeting']

    if membersToHeldMeeting and len(membersToHeldMeeting) == 0:
        return Response({'detail': 'No Appointment Has Been Set'}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
    else:

        # (1) Create Appointment

        createappointment = MakeAppointment.objects.create(
            user=user,
            reasonOfAppointment=data['reasonOfAppointment'],
            meetingWillBeConductedOn=data['meetingWillBeConductedOn'],
            paymentMethod=data['paymentMethod'],
            taxPrice=data['taxPrice'],
            consultancyServiceFee=data['consultancyServiceFee'],
            totalFee=data['totalFee']
        )

        # (2) Create AppointmentDetails

        appointmentdetails = AppointmentDetails.objects.create(
            appointment=appointment,
            appointmentReason=data['appointmentDetails']['appointmentReason'],
            dateOfBirth=data['appointmentDetails']['dateOfBirth'],
            gender=data['appointmentDetails']['gender'],
            maritalStatus=data['appointmentDetails']['maritalStatus'],
            phoneNumber=data['appointmentDetails']['phoneNumber'],
            emergencyContactNo=data['appointmentDetails']['emergencyContactNo'],
            medicalHistory=data['appointmentDetails']['medicalHistory'],
            previousTreatmentDetails=data['appointmentDetails']['previousTreatmentDetails'],
            allergicTo=data['appointmentDetails']['allergicTo'],
            address=data['appointmentDetails']['address'],
            city=data['appointmentDetails']['city'],
            postalCode=data['appointmentDetails']['postalCode'],
            country=data['appointmentDetails']['country'],
        )

        # (3) Create all appointments and set appointment to MembersOfPanelToHeldMeeting relationship
        for i in allAppointments:
            panelmember = PanelMember.objects.get(_id=i['panelmember'])

            allmeetings = MembersOfPanelToHeldMeeting.objects.create(
                panel=panel,
                appointment=appointment,
                name=panelmember.name,
                totalFee=i[''],
                image=panelmember.image.url,
            )

            

        serializer = MakeAppointmentSerializer(createappointment, many=False)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

`serializer.py`

```
class AppointmentDetailsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = AppointmentDetails
        fields = '__all__'

class MembersOfPanelToHeldMeetingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MembersOfPanelToHeldMeeting
        fields = '__all__'

class MakeAppointmentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    membersToHeldMeeting = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)
    appointmentDetailsFromSerilizer = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)
    user = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = MakeAppointment
        fields = '__all__'

    def get_membersToHeldMeeting(self, obj):
        members = obj.membersofpaneltoheldmeeting_set.all()
        serializer = MembersOfPanelToHeldMeetingSerializer(members, many=True)
        return serializer.data

    def get_appointmentDetails(self, obj):
        try:
            details = AppointmentDetailsSerializer(
                obj.appointmentDetailsFromSerilizer, many=False).data
        except:
            details = False
        return details

    def get_user(self, obj):
        user = obj.user
        serializer = UserSerializer(user, many=False)
        return serializer.data
```

Now take a look into react side

`actions.js`

```
export const createAppointment = (appointment) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
    try {
        dispatch({
            type: MEETING_CREATE_REQUEST
        })

        const {
            userLogin: { userInfo },
        } = getState()

        const config = {
            headers: {
                'Content-type': 'application/json',
                Authorization: `Bearer ${userInfo.token}`
            }
        }

        const { data } = await axios.post(
            `/api/appointment/make/`,
            appointment,
            config
        )

        dispatch({
            type: MEETING_CREATE_SUCCESS,
            payload: data
        })

        dispatch({
            type: MEETINGS_CART_PANEL_MEMBERS_CLEAR,
            payload: data
        })

        localStorage.removeItem('meetingConductingMembers')


    } catch (error) {
        dispatch({
            type: MEETING_CREATE_FAIL,
            payload: error.response && error.response.data.detail
                ? error.response.data.detail
                : error.message,
        })
    }
}
```

`reducers.js`

```
export const meetingCreateReducer = (state = {}, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case MEETING_CREATE_REQUEST:
            return {
                loading: true
            }

        case MEETING_CREATE_SUCCESS:
            return {
                loading: false,
                success: true,
                order: action.payload
            }

        case MEETING_CREATE_FAIL:
            return {
                loading: false,
                error: action.payload
            }

        case MEETING_CREATE_RESET:
            return {}


        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

I'm pushing data as .

```
const placeAppointment = () => {
    dispatch(
      createAppointment({
        membersToHeldMeeting: meetingsConductingCart.membersToHeldMeeting,
        appointmentDetails: meetingsConductingCart.appointmentDetails, //this seem not accurate
        paymentMethod: meetingsConductingCart.paymentMethod,
        reasonOfAppointment: meetingsConductingCart.appointmentReason,
        taxPrice: meetingsConductingCart.taxPrice,
        consultancyServiceFee: meetingsConductingCart.consultancyServiceFee,
        totalFee: meetingsConductingCart.totalFee,
      })
    );
```

dispatching this I get

```
KeyError: 'membersToHeldMeeting'
[18/Jul/2021 10:43:28] "POST /api/appointment/make/ HTTP/1.1" 500 106441
```

**Can you Identify where the problem would be and how to fix this. thanx**

Comment: Replace this `membersToHeldMeeting = data['membersToHeldMeeting']` to `membersToHeldMeeting = data.get('membersToHeldMeeting')`

Comment: No that wasn't the problem, there was problem in `localstrage` data, I wasn't naming them correctly as `django` was expecting. Thanx for the comment btw 
@Pradip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

I wasn't constructing the data correctly at frontend for `POST` request

Problem was on fronted

```
const placeAppointment = () => {
    dispatch(
      createAppointment({
        membersToHeldMeeting: meetingsConductingCart.meetingConductingMembers, #this line was changed for that exact error. 
        appointmentDetails: meetingsConductingCart.appointmentDetails, 
        paymentMethod: meetingsConductingCart.meetingsPaymentMethod,
        reasonOfAppointment:
          meetingsConductingCart.appointmentDetails.appointmentReason,
        meetingWillBeConductedOn:
          meetingsConductingCart.appointmentDetails.meetingWillBeConductedOn,
        taxPrice: meetingsConductingCart.taxPrice,
        consultancyServiceFee: meetingsConductingCart.consultancyServiceFee,
        totalFee: meetingsConductingCart.grandtotalFee,
        })
```